# The Three Little Pigs are hiding something

Tags: cipher

As you work through one of your countless puzzle books, you find a sheet of paper inside with a poem on it. Remembering [the last time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25055/8949) you found something like that, you decide to take a crack at this one, hoping to solve it a bit more quickly...

> **A Fable**
>
> The three little pigs hid a little rhyme, 
>   But it's only a matter of how much time 
>   Until the big bad wolf commits the big bad crime 
>   And blows their whole house down.
>
> “Mark my words, pigs, count on these: 
>   I'll find those hidden rhymes with ease, 
>   I'll find those letters and those ABC's 
>   And split them into threes!”
>
> The big bad wolf said this little rhyme, 
>   And he committed the big bad crime, 
>   And he cooked all three of the pigs with thyme, 
>   Wolfing his bacon down.

Nonsense indeed! But what is the fable hiding?

---

**Hint:**

> Upon closer inspection of the poem, you notice that some words have a faint underline, perhaps hinting at a ciphering method: words, count, rhymes, letters, threes, bacon

**Hint 2:**

> Treat each line as a unit, and ignore the stanza breaks. The number 3 is *very* important.

Comment: Well, we need what we're trying to find!

Comment: @bleh a two-word phrase is hidden in the fable using a variant of a cipher which (among other things) is hinted at in the fable itself.

Comment: btw, this phrase "And he cooked all three of the pigs with thyme, " made me sad :-)

Comment: @Volatility I've been trying to crack this one for hours. Could you give us some hints? Is the metering significant? I feel like the rhyming scheme definitely is, judging from the references to "rhymes" in the poem. "ABC's" implies a polyalphabetic cipher to me. "And split them into threes!" may be a hint towards a transposition cipher. I am having trouble identifying the ciphertext though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is using a [Baconian cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher), but I'm not sure what is representing the As and Bs.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I suspect a variant using ABCs rather than just As and Bs, especially since a group of three such symbols ("split them into threes") has 27 possible states - just enough for the alphabet. Still no idea how to get those symbols, though.

Comment: Does Hint #2 imply that each "unit" it mentions is a single letter in the solution?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain no, it just means the solution is encoded in the lines and not anything else.

Comment: After learning the answer (via @Zandar below), I wish I could upvote this multiple times!  An amazing puzzle!  The ingenuity required to come up with something like this is incredible.  Well done!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain thanks! The puzzle wasn't too hard to create - once I had a suitable text to encode, all I needed to do was write something that actually encoded it. It was a bit of a challenge putting in hints that made some sort of sense in the poem though. I'm glad you enjoyed it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue about **bacon** hints at a *[Baconian cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon%27s_cipher)*.  [Zandar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12511) suggested that it might be a variant of the Baconian cipher that uses a ternary instead of a binary system.  So I started by assigning a pattern to each letter, using the values `A, B, C`:

```
AAA  A            BAA  J            CAA  S
AAB  B            BAB  K            CAB  T
AAC  C            BAC  L            CAC  U
ABA  D            BBA  M            CBA  V
ABB  E            BBB  N            CBB  W
ABC  F            BBC  O            CBC  X
ACA  G            BCA  P            CCA  Y
ACB  H            BCB  Q            CCB  Z
ACC  I            BCC  R            CCC  (unassigned)
```

Then I tried to figure out a way to get a pattern out of the poem.  Based on the clue words `word`, `count`, and `threes`, and with the help of the second hint, I counted the words in each line, and assigned each line a letter as follows:

- number of words is divisible by 3:  `A`
- number of words $\div$ 3 leaves a remainder of 1: `B`
- number of words $\div$ 3 leaves a remainder of 2: `C`

(as a more mathematical way of looking at it, use `0`, `1`, `2` instead of `A`, `B`, `C`, and just use (word count $\text{mod}$ 3) to assign a value)

This left me with the following:

```
          Word                Letter
 Line #   count   Remainder   assigned
 1        8       2           C
 2        9       0           A
 3       10       1           B
 4        6       0           A
 5        7       1           B
 6        7       1           B
 7        7       1           B
 8        5       2           C
 9        8       2           C
10        7       1           B
11       10       1           B
12        4       1           B
```

This leaves us with four triplets:  `CAB`, `ABB`, `BCC`, `BBB`

If we refer back to our alphabet table, these correspond to the letters

> **`T`, `E`, `R`, `N`**.

Now if we look at the rhyme scheme of the poem, we get another pattern, based on which words rhyme with each other:  AAAB CCCC AAAB.

Splitting that into triplets, we get `AAA`, `BCC`, `CCA`, `AAB`, which correspond to the letters

> **`A`, `R`, `Y`, `B`**.

If we do the same thing a third time, this time using the *letter* count instead of the word count, we end up with the sequence AAAAACBBCBBB.

Splitting that into triplets, we get `AAA`, `AAC`, `BBC`, `BBB`, which correspond to the letters

> **`A`, `C`, `O`, `N`**.

Putting these three results together, we get

> **`TERNARYBACON`** or ***Ternary bacon***, which describes the cipher used in encrypting this.

---

> *A huge thanks to Zandar who actually solved most of this, and SpiritFryer as well.*

Comment: Its a two word phrase, according to the OP.

Comment: Good start, but you still need to consider the rhymes and the letters to get the complete solution.

Comment: The rhyming scheme is AAAB, CCCC, AAAB, which split into threes gives us AAA (= A), BCC ( = R), CCA (= Y), AAB (= B). Those don't seem to make any sensible word though.

Comment: Counting the letters in the same way as the words gives AAA AAC BBC BBB, which translates to ACON. I kind of expected that would be the solution once I saw the first part.

Comment: @Zandar Now if only the first stanza had a rhyme scheme of ABA or ABC or CAB, we could combine the two to get `DRY BACON` or `FRY BACON` or `TRY BACON`.

Comment: No, I mean along with the words and rhymes, the whole thing gives TERNARY BACON.

Comment: @Zandar OH!  <light bulb comes on>  Now I get it.  Why don't you post that as an answer, then?  You came up with the initial "ternary bacon cipher" idea, and you've solved most of the rest of it as well; you definitely deserve the credit.

Comment: @Zandar Feel free to cut and paste my existing answer and then expand on it.

Comment: @Volatility Zandar doesn't seem interested in posting an answer himself/herself, so I've filled this one in with the rest of the solution. Hopefully it's complete now.

Comment: Well done. As a bonus, the title is also reflective of the answer (ternary bacon is enciphering something).